# How to exclude assets from apostrophe-site-map coming from AWS S3

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3, apostrophe-cms

This is a very plugin specific question to ask. But I am using this plugin https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-site-map which is for integration with Apostrophe CMS and I have no idea where else to ask this question.
https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/

In the documentation for the sitemap generator, there is this example of how to exclude certain types of content.

```
{
    'apostrophe-site-map': {
        excludeTypes: [ 'apostrophe-blog-post' ]
    }
}
```

But I am trying to stop all of the uploads from showing up on the sitemap. PDFs and JPGs etc.. Currently every single asset that has been uploaded from the cms to AWS S3 is showing up. We want to stop this from happening.

Is there a way to do this with the plugin API or do we need another solution to generate the sitemap?

Or is there an alternative way to stop this (without using Cloudfront) on S3 side?

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that by adding them to the `excludeTypes` option of `apostrophe-site-map`, like this:

```
// in app.js where you configure the module
apostrophe-site-map: {
  // singular names, not module names, these are used in the type
  // property of each doc
  excludeTypes: [ 'apostrophe-image', 'apostrophe-file' ]
}
```

They are showing up in the sitemap because they have a `_url` property but you can add them to the list to be excluded. It is probable that we should do this by default for images. PDFs, I'm not so sure about the best default.

Comment: ok cool. thanks for the response! I will check this out. That is helpful, we just couldn't figure out what the type was to be called in that array. Once the sitemap was uploaded to google they gave us errors for all of the pdfs and technically I don't think they indexed them. I will run your code through soon, but for now you can see what is being generated on our end. https://www.eaupalmbeach.com/sitemap.xml - ironically, the pdfs don't even live on our server, so that may be the reason they are getting errors...

Comment: Excuse me, you should be excluding `apostrophe-image` and `apostrophe-file`, rather than the module names (the singular names are used in the type property of each doc, which is what this is looking for).

Comment: Hi Tom, is there a means to exclude individual pages (presumably slugs?) from the sitemap, rather than entire types?  I'm seeing "Submitted URL marked ‘noindex’" in Google Search Console, which appears to be because I have a couple of pages that I have marked as noindex/nofollow in Apostrophe showing up in the sitemap.